# Copy Array With Extra Characters in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I want to add the same string to a list but with extra text, example:

```py
a = ['1', '2']
b = ['text', 'foo', 'bar']
```

I want this to become

```py
['text', 'foo', 'bar', 'text1', 'foo1', 'bar1', 'text2', 'foo2', 'bar2']
```

Comment: this site is not for doing what you want for you, it's for helping you to solve yourt problem yourself

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We need to create a new list for result with elements of b list. We can use nested loop to iterate over both lists and to append combination of elements.

```
a = ['1','2']
b = ['text','foo','bar']

result = [itemb for itemb in b]
for itema in a:
    for itemb in b:
        result.append(itemb+itema)
print(result)
```

It will print `['text', 'foo', 'bar', 'text1', 'foo1', 'bar1', 'text2', 'foo2', 'bar2']`